# Why is it impossible to have different integration results in cartesian and polar coordinates?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, supremum-and-infimum, multiple-integral

Let $A$ be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable function on $A$.

We have to find the multiple integral of function $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

By definition of Riemann Integral:

- In Cartesian coordinates, $\iint_A f(x,y)\ dA=\text{lub} \{  L(P,f)  \}$ where $P$ is any rectangular partition of $A$.
- In polar coordinates, $\iint_A f(r,\theta)\ dA=\text{lub} \{  L(P',f)  \}$ where $P'$ is any circular sector partition of $A$.

I know $\text{lub} \{  L(P,f)  \}$ and $\text{lub} \{  L(P',f)  \}$ are equal? But how can we prove this?

Comment: I think the proof for this would be about as complicated as the more general theorem relating integration, any change of variables, and the Jacobian determinant. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote?

Comment: @aschepler: Please can you provide a link to the proof of the theorem?

Comment: I don't know a good online source. Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds contains a proof on pages 67-72, but that's just what I happen to have on hand. Probably other texts have more accessible proofs.

Comment: There's also https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChangeofVariablesTheorem.html.

Comment: Be careful here. The polar $dA$ is different! But you can probably use the formula for area of a polar annulus and concoct inscribed and circumscribed partitions one way and the other and give an ad hoc proof.